# Display JSON on profilepage

Tags: php, json

How to display the names of accounts on user's profile page? So there would be displayed holidays and savings next to Accounts:

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to display the names of accounts (not the id) that user has and it should be displayed on their profile page. The accounts are saved in clients.json file. Thanks for help!

data/clients.json

```
{
    "data": {
        "tomas": {
            "name": "eter",
            "accounts": {
                "5c7072a835c3b": {
                    "balance": 1000,
                    "name": "savings"
                },
                "5c7072a835c36": {
                    "balance": 1000,
                    "name": "holidays"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my PHP file :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['sUserId'])) {
        header('Location: login.php');
    }

    $sUserId = $_SESSION['sUserId'];

    $sData = file_get_contents('data/clients.json');
    $jData = json_decode($sData);
    if ($jData == null) {
        echo 'System update';
    }

    $sTotalBalance = array_sum(array_column((array)$jData->data->$sUserId->accounts, 'balance'));

    require_once 'top.php';
?>

<div><h5>Username:</h5> <?php echo $sUserId; ?></div>
<div><h5>Name: </h5><?php echo $jData->data->$sUserId->name; ?></div>
<div><h5>Accounts: </h5><?php echo $jData->data->$sUserId->accounts; ?> kr </div>

<?php
    $sLinkToScript = '<script src="js/profile.js"></script>';
    require_once 'bottom.php';
?>
```

Comment: and what is the question here?

Comment: @devpro  how to display the names of accounts on user's profile page? So there would be displayed holidays and savings next to Accounts:

Comment: replace this line `$jData = json_decode($sData);` with `$jData = json_decode($sData,true);` then use `print_r($jData);` and share the result.

Comment: ALRIGHT.    `Array ( [data] => Array ( [tomas] => Array ( [name] => eter [accounts] => Array ( [5c7072a835c3b] => Array ( [balance] => 1000 [name] => savings ) [5c7072a835c36] => Array ( [balance] => 1000 [name] => holidays ) ) ) ) )`

Comment: so `tomas == $sUserId` right???

Comment: and what is the issue with this `<?php echo $jData->data->$sUserId->name; ?>` is it not working???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try iterating it as follows -

```
foreach($jData->data->$sUserId->accounts as $acc) {
    echo $acc->name;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to separate them so if user has more accounts, names will note look like SavingsHolidays but they will be separated by coma or written one below another.

Comment: `$accCount = count($jData->data->$sUserId->accounts);
    foreach($jData->data->$sUserId->accounts as $acc) {
        echo ($accCount > 0) ? $acc->name . ', ' : $acc->name;
        $accCount--;
    }`